# Starting late for retirement

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan

I am 68 years old and am a minister.  Hope to keep working indefinitely.  Wife and I have no debts and have just begun to put our SSA money into savings and a Roth IRA.  What other investments would be wise for people our age?

Comment: What are you investing in, inside of your Roth IRA?

Comment: Any investment that you understand fully. If you don't have any understanding of any investments then you should seek advice from a Financial Planner.

Answer (score 2):

I would make this a comment, but I am not worthy......

You will need to define your objectives before you can do anything.

What is the money for?  What is your risk tolerance?  Where do you live?  Capital appreciation?  Preservation?  Can you eat if your savings are cut in half?  How much are you currently making?  How much are you currently saving?  What do you already have exposure to?  How secure is your job?  What is the makeup of the congregation?  Do you have any tax-related surprises?  Do you own your home?  Have you previously consulted with a financial planner?

There are many many factors obviously.  More than I think most people want to give out over the internet, but they are all important to making a decision.  Get a recommendation from someone you know for a financial planner.  Ask upfront what their background is.  Education, experience credentials.  You want a certified financial planner or analyst.  Ask how their fees are structured and what their approach is like, and make sure they're speaking intelligibly.  Feel free to shop around until you find someone you like.

Comment: Note: when seeking a financal planner, pick an independent rather than someone who wants to actually manage your money for you.. They will charge for the service,  but they won't be biased toward recommending whatever brings them the most commission. Good advice matters and is worth paying for.